# python/redmine retrieve value of a custom_field

Tags: python, redmine, python-redmine

With redminelib, I'm trying to retrieve value of custom_fields, when the custom_field is a key/value in redmine.

In `issue.custom_fields.get(109)`, we've got:

- id of the custom_field
- name of the custom_field
- value which is actually the key index of the key/value item, but not the value

So how can I get the value of a key/value item, once I've got the key index?

Thanks,
Raoul

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not find it at first, but indeed there is a custom_fields resource that you can request: https://python-redmine.com/resources/custom_field.html#

Answer (score 0):

so you have custom fields

```
>>>issue[0]['custom_fields'][1]
['id', 'name', 'value']
```

custom field name

```
>>>issue[0]['custom_fields'][1]['name']
'Custom1'
```

custom field value

```
>>>issue[0]['custom_fields'][1]['value']
'Value test'
```

gess that may help